# JQuery: Attribute selector doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, selector

Given the following code, I would expect an alert of "searchRes1" which is a direct match of the id, and for the second block, i would expect it to alert the other two div's as well since id contains "search".  What am i missing?

```
            <div id="sRes">
               <h4>Search for things</h4> 
                <div id="searchRes1">123</div>
                <div id="searchRes2">456</div>
                <div id="searchRes3">789</div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $("#sRes div[id='searchRes1']").each(function () {
                    alert($(this).attr("id"));
                });

                $("#sRes div[id~='search']").each(function() {
                    alert($(this).attr("id"));
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: what does it alert in the second selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS selectors, *contains* (`~=`) means *contains the full word*. This can be useful for things like `rel="foo bar"` which would be matched by `rel~='foo'`, `rel~='bar'` but not `rel~='fo'`.

Try with *startsWith* (`^=`):

```
$("#sRes div[id^='search']")
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

Comment: Ok this works... i should of read the documentation more carefully since it explicitly states:
This selector matches the test string against each word in the attribute value, where a "word" is defined as a string delimited by whitespace. The selector matches if the test string is exactly equal to any of the words.

User error for the fail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the first one is working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/raW26/

And for the [second](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) one to work i think the attribute that you're selecting must be delimited by spaces

You must use `*=` or `^=` for it to work

P.S. you don't need to use `$(this).attr("id")` just `this.id` is enough

```
$("#sRes div[id='searchRes1']").each(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
        });

        $("#sRes div[id*='search']").each(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

u miss the name and also use `!` not `~`

```
$("#sRes div[id!='searchRes1']").each(function() {
                    alert($(this).attr("id"));
                });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rPSGR/2/)

#### [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)